# How to implement password field which will enable or disable use of menu bar

Tags: java, swing, passwords, jmenu

Basically what I would like to do is have a password field on my main menu jframe which will either allow a user to select from the menu bar on the jframe.  If they do not get the password correct, they cannot select anything from any of the menu items in the menu bar, hence they will not be able to use the menu.  I know how to implement a password field, but how do I connect it to use of the main menu bar?  Much appreciation in advance.  BTW, I have code written for the menu bar, but none for the password field yet, that is why I didn't post the code yet.

Comment: You should *Always* post code that is relevant (meaning you should finish it and then ask about it). Also - do you mean adding the text field to the *menu bar* or just having it on the `JFrame`?

Comment: Make the menu bar invisble or disabled, and once you have checked that the password is correct, make it visible or enabled. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: I added the password textfield to the main jframe.

Comment: with an OK button.

Comment: Code in comments is nearly unreadable; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind for my next question....sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use JPasswordField like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JMenuBar mb = new JMenugBar();
/* here you create all the menu*/ 
char[] password = "123456"; 
JButton button = new JButton("OK");
JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(JPasswordField.getPassword.equals(password){
            frame.add(mb);
        }
});
frame.add(pf);
frame.add(button);
```